# Qual calculo pra converter um 'CodePoint' pra UTF-16?

Tags: unicode

Eu tenho um inteiro de 32 bits representando um caractere unicode e gostaria de converter este único caractere em sua representação utf-16 , ou seja, um ou mais inteiros de 16 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O formato de transformação do unicode, 16 bits (UTF-16) está definido na [seção 2.5 do padrão Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch02.pdf#G11153), bem como na [RFC 2781](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2781). Ela funciona da seguinte maneira:

1. Seja o *codepoint* `U` o valor que você quer codificar. Se `U` for menor que 65.536, emita-o normalmente.
2. Se `U` for maior ou igual a 65.536, obtenha `U' = U - 65536`. Esse `U'`, pelas regras do Unicode, vai ter os 12 bits mais significativos iguais a zero (já que o último *codepoint* válido é `0x10FFFF`).
3. Emita dois bytes, em ordem:

   1. o primeiro tem os seis bits mais significativos `1101 10` e os dez menos significativos iguais aos dez bits mais significativos de `U'`.
   2. O segundo tem os seis bits mais significativos `1101 11` e os dez menos significativos iguais aos dez bits menos significativos de `U'`.

Em C:

```
void
utf_16(uint32_t codepoint, FILE * out) {
    uint32_t U;
    uint16_t W;

    assert(codepoint <= 0x10FFFF);
    if (codepoint < 0x10000) {
        W = (uint16_t) codepoint;
        fwrite(W, sizeof(W), 1, out);
    } else {
        U = codepoint - 0x10000;
        W = 0xD800 | (U >> 10);
        fwrite(W, sizeof(W), 1, out);
        W = 0xDC00 | (U & 0x3FF);
        fwrite(W, sizeof(W), 1, out);
    }
}
```

Comment: isso sim é resposta ! funcionou perfeitamente